# When to stop the animation while using animateImageWithImages in apple watch

Tags: ios, watchkit, apple-watch

I am using animateImageWithImages for animation in watch kit, but there is no property to check that animation is done unlike iPhone where we can put it in block or can check using isAnimating property. How we will come to know that when to stop the animation in watch kit?

Answer (score 1):

I'm using a WKInterfaceImage to make an animation. For example you have a WKInterfaceImage with animate duration is 2 second. so you can start and stop the animate after 2 second using delay function like this:

```
 self.animateImage.startAnimating()//Start animate the image
//delay function in 2 seconds, after 2 seconds and we will stop the animated image 
        dispatch_after(dispatch_time(
            DISPATCH_TIME_NOW,
            Int64(2 * Double(NSEC_PER_SEC))
            ), dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in
                self.animateImage.stopAnimating()
                //you can write some function in here after finish the anim
        })
```

Comment: I am also doing the same thing but it is not accurate.